# find in a Bash while loop ignores iterator's first value

Tags: bash

Why in the following bash script doesn't `$ID` in the `find` line have any value during the first iteration of the while loop?

```sh
while read -r ID
do
    echo $ID
    cd "`find . -iname "*($ID)"`"  # ← This is the problem line.
    pwd
    cd -
    echo
done < IDs.csv
```

Here's the trace of the first iteration

```sh
+ read -r ID
+ echo 6518
6518
++ find . -iname '*(6518)' # ← find always returns nothing first iteration.
+ cd ''
+ pwd
/home/Geremia
+ cd /home/Geremia
+ echo
```

But successive iterations work just fine:

```sh
+ read -r ID
+ echo 6556
6556
++ find . -iname '*(6556)' # ← find returns path all successive iterations.
+ cd './found/dir (6556)'
+ pwd
/home/found/dir (6556)
+ cd /home/Geremia
+ echo
```

This always occurs, even if I put `6556`, for example, at the beginning of the CSV file.

Comment: Which directory are you in when you first run the script?

Comment: @cdarke Doing that gives: `find . -iname *(): command not found`, `find . -iname *(6518): command not found`, etc.

Comment: @Geremia: OK, sorry, ignore that

Comment: @Geremia Where is the script? Obviously if the script is in `/home/found/bin` and your target directory is `/home/found/dir (6518)`, then it will fail on the first iteration because you're looking from `.`

Comment: @thatotherguy The script is in `/home/Geremia`

Comment: My guess is there's a non-printing character at the beginning of the file. Maybe a BOM character?

Comment: What does `echo "$ID" | od -x` show?

Comment: TIL that even bash4 fails to show BOMs in xtrace output -___-

Comment: @Barmar For the first iteration: `0000000 bbef 36bf 3135 0a38
0000010`

Comment: There are 3 bytes before the number `6518` there: `EF` `BB`, `BF`. That's a BOM in UTF-8: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8